# When designing structure of Deep neural net, why are numbers 256, 512, 32, 16 etc?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, layer, convolution

Is there a hard-ware reason why, say the number of nodes in a layer, is a power of 2?

Comment: its a convention

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% certain most machine learning developers choose those numbers just because they increase it in orders of 2 until it works. No hardware reasons.